# install yslow for chrome 67 giving invalid manifest

Tags: yslow

I have tried updating chrome and tried to install yslow in "incognito" window.
After that when I install yslow for chrome 67 its giving invalid manifest. My system is windows 10 and chrome is up to date.

Thanks,
Sulagna

Answer (score 0):

It is an open issue in yslow. Even if you update the manifest by downloading the .crx from [chrome extension downloader](https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) and convert it to a zip file and extract the manifest and update it according to the new version. You will still run into issues. Here is the [link](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/issues/197) to the issue. 
You can download yslow from the [url](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yslow/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh) and [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.) are the changes for new version. You will have to add `"manifest_version": 2` to manifest.json and also update the `background_page` to `background`. And then load the extension in chrome.